# What does “Je me balade avec ma propre musique d'ambiance” mean?

Tags: sens

[image: Button Pin]

*I'm having a hard time finding out what does it mean.*

Comment: We are not a translation service so we appreciate OPs to say what they have found so far and why they do not think it's good enough for their purpose.

Comment: Where did you get the badge?

Comment: [Search it first.. Takes few seconds](http://www.babelfish.fr/dict?query=Je+me+balade+avec+ma+propre+musique+d%27ambiance&src=auto&dst=en&submit=Traduire)

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of this sentence is not specific to French language. You can translate it directly and then try to understand by yourself.
It looks like an old badge probably worn by "walkman" users, when such a device was considered as very "high-tech".

Answer (score 2):

As Gregala wrote, it is probably a badge worn by early Walkman adopters from back when it was considered a high-tech device.

The word "baladeur" was created by the *Office québécois de la langue française* back in 1989. In France, the *Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie* accepted the word in 2000. It is a neologism for "Walkman" that comes from the verb "balader," which means **to wander around, to take for a walk, to stroll**.

The sentence means: "I wander around with my own ambient music."

Comment: "... my own ambient music" is spot on, but either "... my own background music" or "... my own mood music" would probably work, too.